# Javascript button - Upon click, other buttons slide up from behind it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, less, pug

I'm very new to JS and JQuery, and I'm trying to finish up a request that involves buttons that slide up.
Steps:

1. User clicks on 'Expand' button.
2. Activates JS, 4 social media buttons slide upwards. User than can click one of the buttons to open a pop up to share the page (this is already set up).
3. User can close this menu by clicking the 'Expand' button again.

   ```
   .share-button-group {
       position: fixed;
       bottom: 60px;
       right: 30px;
       z-index: 999;

       a + a {
           margin-top: @padding-small-horizontal;
       }
   }

   .share-button-expand {
       .share-button-variant(@gray-light, '\f1e0');
   }

   .share-button-facebook {
       .share-button-variant(#3b5998, '\f09a');
   }
   ```

And here it is in our Jade-esque markup (extremely similar, just small tweaks)

```
    if share
      .share-button-group
        a.share-button-facebook(data-share="facebook")
          span.sr-only Share on Facebook 
        a.share-button-expand(data-share="expand")
          span.sr-only Share
```

This is how the buttons are set up in LESS. How can I target the 'Expand' button so that when clicked, the four buttons behind it will appear? I know to wait until the document is ready and that it's a click(function()) but that's as far as I've been able to find. I'm working in a Jade like language, with Bootstrap as well.
 Thanks!

EDIT: Figured I'd include an image to show the thought process.

[image: Sorry it's so horrible, I'm super exhausted as well.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using jQuery you can use the .on() event listener to detect the click of the 'expand' button and then use .slideToggle() to handle the share button reveal/hiding.

```js
$('.expandBtn').on( "click", function() {
  $('.shareItems').slideToggle( "slow", function() {
    // Animation complete.
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="shareItems" style="display:none;">
    <a href="">Facebook</a>
    <a href="">Twitter</a>
</div>
<div class="expandBtn">
    <a href="javascript:;">Expand</a>
</div>
```

[See this fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/wrmn16uo/)

Comment: I totally forgot to include an image, but will this work if I want each link targeted? I have an image now on the question.

Comment: Yes, absolutely. Just place the image inside of the A tags (replacing the text).

Comment: See this updated Fiddle using images: https://jsfiddle.net/wrmn16uo/2/
Not much changes. Please be sure to check this answer as accepted if it works for you. Cheers.

Comment: YES thank you so much! This actually makes sense to me as well, so I can learn from it too!

Comment: Is there a webpage that can tell me how to add variable effects to this? And how to hide the buttons from being seen when they rise up from behind the share button?